# How to edit or customize content of JMeter Dashboard Report generated in Jmeter v5.0?

Tags: jmeter, test-report

I need to know what and where to change

1. if I have to add an extra table in the dashboart report
2. or if I wanted to add some extra metrics in the Statistics summary to show in the dashboard report. For example, if I want to
   display timestamp as a column in Statistics table of Dashboard
   report on UI. The timestamp values are already available in the
   summaryreport.jtl file generated when the test cases are run but it
   does not show up on the dashboard report UI.
3. If Statistics table should display the result according to Execution timings or timestamp(Exact structure like the summary
   report file generated)

The dashboard report in its default is not that easy to understand for all and thus customizations are needed.
I'm sure there would be a way to achieve this even if it involves changing of classes/jars/plugins.Please suggest.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jMeter is an open source project, so you can change the code or hire a developer to change the code for you. You can find the code [here](https://github.com/apache/jmeter). You could also create a enhancement request in [their Bugzilla](http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html).

Some configuration of the dashboards is possible according to the [jMeter dashboard documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html), it also includes a link to a developer page for improving the dashboard:

> 14.6 Want to improve Report Dashboard ? If you want to contribute new graphs or improve current ones, you can read this [**developer documentation**](http://jmeter.apache.org/devguide-dashboard.html).

Comment: Thanks. I guess that requires some good amount of analysis and changes